# Is this a proper use of a temporary std::string?

Tags: c++, object-lifetime

```
std::string getMyString() { return <make a string>; }

...

HANDLE something = OpenSomething(getMyString().c_str(), ...);
```

I've read [Guaranteed lifetime of temporary in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584824/guaranteed-lifetime-of-temporary-in-c) and I believe that the temporary string will live until the assignment has been evaluated, i.e. plenty long enough to make this work as expected.

Having once before run into an `std::string` lifetime-related bug (can't remember what it was) I'd rather double-check...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is fine. :-)

The string will be destroyed at the end of the statement, at the semi colon.

Answer (score 8):

The destructor for the temporary will not be called until after the function call returns, so what we see here is safe.

**However** if the called function saves the `char*` and it ends up being used somehow *after* `OpenSomething` has returned, then that's one fine dangling pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use any other argument of `OpenSomthing` for returning pointer to `getMyString.c_str()` everything will be OK.