# What is the difference between const char * and literal string?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on a form which has QT widget, I have to set some value in a QTextEdit field.
I had to call a function which is declared like :

```
 void SDB::setDescription(const char *Description);
```

and when I call it by this method (i)

```
const char * desc = saveOptionsDesLineEditBox->text().toStdString().c_str();
SDB::setDescription(desc);
```

It shows unrecognised symbol in the widget's text box.
but by calling by this second method (ii)

```
SDB::setDescription(saveOptionsDesLineEditBox->text().toStdString().c_str());
```

works fine.
Why there is difference between these two methods?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449368/is-this-a-proper-use-of-a-temporary-stdstring

Dangling pointer

Comment: @0A0D I read this line on your mentioned link : The destructor for the temporary will not be called until after the function call returns. I guess this clears the doubt for me, thank you :)
And so it means, in the called function I can use this value anywhere but once control returns, use of this would have undefined behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `std::string` returned by `saveOptionsDesLineEditBox->text().toStdString()` is a temporary. It goes out of scope at the end of the line, and is destroyed, along with its contents. **Therefore, referring to the contained `const char*` returned by `c_str()` through `desc` in the next line is undefined behaviour.**

---

When you call

```
SDB::setDescription(saveOptionsDesLineEditBox->text().toStdString().c_str());
```

all in the same statement, the temporary exists for long enough that `setDescription` can read and copy the c string safely.

I'd suggest something along the lines of

```
std::string desc = saveOptionsDesLineEditBox->text().toStdString();
SDB::setDescription(desc.c_str());
```

Strictly speaking this will incur one copy more than necessary (or a move if you have `c++11`), but who really cares here. Making the code simpler to understand is a good thing in its own right.

(Note, this is a guess, not having seen any of the function signatures, but it is pretty likely a good one.)

Comment: Incidentally, in case anyone was thinking of it, I thought mentioning the "most important `const`" trick to avoid the extra copy was probably a bit much for the asker at this point. For those interested, see http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/ If you don't fully understand the lifetime of temporaries, don't worry about how you can change it.

Answer (score 3):

I guess .toStdString() returns a std::string, not a . std::string& to some stable object.

If so, it is a temporary, that will be destroyed at the end of the full expression (that is the last ; in the line). Before that you asked a const char* from that temporary, and store it. When it is valid only as long as string lives.

You can fix the situation like this:

```
const auto& desc = saveOptionsDesLineEditBox->text().toStdString();
SDB::setDescription(desc.c_str());
```

or just put the whole expression in the setDescription call.