# string.c_str() is const?

Tags: c++

I have a function in a library that takes in a `char*` and modifies the data.

I tried to give it the `c_str()` but c++ docs say it returns a `const char*`.

What can I do other than newing a char array and copying it into that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nothing.

Because `std::string` manages itself its contents, you can't have write access to the string's underlying data. That's undefined behavior.

However, creating and copying a char array is not hard:

```
std::string original("text");
std::vector<char> char_array(original.begin(), original.end());
char_array.push_back(0);

some_function(&char_array[0]);
```

Comment: so I cannot do &string[0] safely?

Comment: Actually, passing `&str[0]` should be well-defined behavior as long as the function does not try to exceed the length of the buffer.

Comment: Ill just copy it into a vector of char and call it a day.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: only in C++11, where it's guaranteed that `std::string`'s contents is contiguous.

Comment: @Fanael Even C++11 still says of `c_str()` and the new `data()`: "Requires: The program shall not alter any of the values stored in the character array." Not sure why.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: C++03 made `std::vector` contiguous, but not `std::string`.

Comment: @MatteoItalia No, C++03 allowed noncontiguous `string` implementations, but nobody ever found such practical so they changed in favor of user flexibility and implementation rigidity.

Comment: @kbok: ugh, performing a copy that way isn't a good idea, you don't have any exception safety; if you really want to be sure use `std::vector<char>` instead, it's guaranteed to be contiguous and is exception-safe.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I think that's in order to let strings implement copy-on-write.

Comment: @kbok ah, of course. Interesting that COW hasn't been deprecated yet.

Comment: You can use the appropriate `vector` constructor to simplify this code: `std::vector buf( s.begin(), s.end() ); buf.push_back( '\0' );`

Comment: I prefer the std copy way, this way is not good for reuse. I'm not just using this once. Copying will not call new and reallocate unless needed.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: SGI found non-contiguous strings useful enough to implement ropes... certainly making it a distinct class is better than choosing that for the `std::string` implementation.  Ahh - I just saw this has also been covered in comments on Matteo's answer....

Comment: @TonyDelroy Yes, I just meant specifically as `std::string`. Nobody should put megabytes of text in a contiguous array… it seems more text editors understood this in the late 80's-early 90's than today.

Comment: `some_function(char_array.data())` can be used just as well.

Answer (score 17):

You can use `&str[0]` or `&*str.begin()` as long as:

- you preallocate explicitly all the space needed for the function with `resize()`;
- the function does not try to exceed the preallocated buffer size (you should pass `str.size()` as the argument for the buffer size);
- when the function returns, you explicitly trim the string at the first `\0` character you find, otherwise `str.size()` will return the "preallocated size" instead of the "logical" string size.

***Notice:*** this is guaranteed to work in C++11 (where strings are guaranteed to be contiguous), but not in previous revisions of the standard; still, no implementation of the standard library that I know of ever did implement `std::basic_string` with noncontiguous storage.

Still, if you want to go safe, use `std::vector<char>` (guaranteed to be contiguous since C++03); initialize with whatever you want (you can copy its data from a string using the constructor that takes two iterators, adding a null character in the end), resize it as you would do with `std::string` and copy it back to a string stopping at the first `\0` character.

Comment: Note: This is only guaranteed in C++11, in C++03 strings could be implemented as ropes (list of discontiguous chunks of memory)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: correct in theory, but nobody ever did it; someone implemented ropes, but as a separated class, I suppose to avoid e.g. making `c_str()` calls expensive or to break all the code that supposes that strings are stored in contiguous memory.

Comment: Just to be safe, you can also explicitly nul-terminate your `string` by adding a 0 character to the end of it before you pass anything to the C function. That way, there's no concern over what happens if the C function writes to the terminator that it finds.

Comment: Actually this is *not* compliant even with C++11: `operator[]`, even the non-const version, requires "the referenced value shall not be modified." It breaks COW. The library could return a shared byte sequence of `n` NUL characters, never allocate a new one, and be totally surprised when you modify it. `&* str.begin()` however does appear kosher.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: [citation needed]

Comment: @Fanael C++11 21.4.3 [string.iterators] doesn't mention not modifying; 21.4.5 [string.access] and 21.4.7.1 [string.accessors] both do.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I think there's some punctuation confusion in `21.4.5/2`. I believe that "the reference shall not be modified" is intended to apply only to the case where `pos == size()`, but that is not clear from the semi-colon. It's confusing because normally in English a comma has higher precedence than a semi-colon.

Comment: @SteveJessop that requires putting the semicolon at higher precedence than the comma. And there is a good argument for COW. And that doesn't explain why [string.accessors] explicitly mentions the entire sequence. (I initially just looked up `data` expecting to verify that it returned non-const, but it's just the same as `c_str`.)

Comment: @SteveJessop: In N3376, it's very much unambiguous: "*Returns*: `*(begin() + pos)` if `pos < size()`. Otherwise, returns a reference to an object of type `charT` with value `charT()`, where modifying the object leads to undefined behavior."

Comment: @Fanael: ah, thanks, I was using the FDIS. Problem solved, no COW in C++11 (or at least if you do implement COW, then you must take your copy when someone calls `operator[]`, not wait for them to actually modify the string).

Comment: Oh… I shouldn't be doing this right now. Because `operator[]` calls `begin`, and `begin` notifies any COW mechanism that a change may occur, then `operator[]` does prepare it for a change.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: if your interpretation were true, `std::string x = "acbd"; x[0] = 'c';` would be illegal, mind you.

Comment: @Fanael Yes, I was thinking COW implementations *would* behave unpredictably in practice, one reason why they're unpopular. (Unlike discontiguous representations, it has been tried.)

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I haven't looked into this properly, but I suppose that if you want to take advantage of any possible COW-ness of the implementation then you restrict yourself to `data()` and `c_str()`. Maybe `operator[] const`, depending whether it's guaranteed to return the same address as `operator[] non-const`, and the same question applies to `begin() const`.

Comment: @SteveJessop Well there's now `cbegin` for that purpose. But it's probably not worth the trouble. If you want pooled strings, use a pooled string class… it's proven that `std::string` should be as plain as possible, COW slows the common case.

Answer (score 3):

If you *know* that the function will not modify beyond `str.size()` you can obtain a pointer in one of different ways:

```
void f( char* p, size_t s ); // update s characters in p
int main() {
   std::string s=...;
   f( &s[0], s.size() );
   f( &s.front(), s.size() );
}
```

Note, this is guaranteed in C++11, but not in previous versions of the standard where it allowed for *rope* implementations (i.e. non-contiguous memory)

Comment: Although the earlier standard allowed rope implementations, the C++ committee found that none had ever been implemented which is why they changed the requirements in C++11. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @Mark: the way Herb Sutter reported it on his blog, they took a straw poll of those present, whether any active implementation used ropes. None did, and no significant C++ implementation was unrepresented at C++0x committee meetings. That's not quite the same as thoroughly investigating whether there has *ever* been a ropey string, but as you say it's enough not to need to worry about it in practice, because the whole point of their question was "will any implementation we care about need to change to support this additional requirement", and the answer was no.

Answer (score 2):

If your implementation will not try to increase the length of the string then:

C++11:

```
std::string data = "This is my string.";
func(&*data.begin());
```

C++03:

```
 std::string data = "This is my string.";
 std::vector<char> arr(data.begin(), data.end());

 func(&arr[0]);
```

Comment: In the C++03 version, `func` will be called with a string which is not necessarily null terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a class that will generate a temporary buffer and automatically copy it to the string when it's destroyed.

```
class StringBuffer
{
public:
    StringBuffer(std::string & str) : m_str(str)
    {
        m_buffer.push_back(0);
    }
    ~StringBuffer()
    {
        m_str = &m_buffer[0];
    }
    char * Size(int maxlength)
    {
        m_buffer.resize(maxlength + 1, 0);
        return &m_buffer[0];
    }
private:
    std::string & m_str;
    std::vector<char> m_buffer;
};
```

And here's how you would use it:

```
// this is from a crusty old API that can't be changed
void GetString(char * str, int maxlength);

std::string mystring;
GetString(StringBuffer(mystring).Size(MAXLEN), MAXLEN);
```

If you think you've seen this code before, it's because I copied it from a question I wrote: [Guaranteed lifetime of temporary in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584824/guaranteed-lifetime-of-temporary-in-c)

Comment: This looks like you reinvented `std::vector<char> buf(MAXLEN); GetString(&buf[0], MAXLEN); std::string s = &buf[0];`.

Comment: I don't like that the destructor of this class can throw.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe, yes, yes I did.