# Any possible issues if const char * is converted to char * in a function call

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In fun1() I am getting a string and I need to pass this string data to a function fun2() which takes argument char *

function2 prototype is as below

```
void fun2(char *p);
```

I am calling fun2 from fun1 as below

```
void fun1()
{
    fun2((char *)str.c_str());
}
```

Is there any chance from the conversion from const char * to char * does make any potential issues

Comment: You're on the train to undefined behaviour if  you try to modify the C-string inside and the initial data is `const`.

Comment: `std::string` is C++, so why is this tagged C? You shouldn't use C-style casts. If `fun2` is a legacy function which can't be changed, but WON'T modify the string, use `const_cast`. If `fun2` could modify the string, use `reinterpret_cast` but this could be undefined behavior and a whole world of hurt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `fun2` tries to modify the data pointed to by the `const char*` returned by `std::string::c_str` then it's undefined behavior.

If `fun2` doesn't modify the data pointed to by `p`, then there won't be any problem. (But then `fun2` should be declared to take a `const char*`, not a `char*`, anyway.)

Comment: It is only UB if the data itself is `const`.

Comment: @juanchopanza you mean that if the `std::string` itself is non-const, then you are OK modifying via `c_str()`?

Comment: @vsoftco No, I was talking of `fun2` and casting away const-ness in general. `std::string` will have extra restrictions.

Comment: Thanks for the response.const char * doesn't allow to point to another memory location .so we can change the data inside that address.please correct me if I am wrong.For me even the data is changed to that pointed address in fun2 it doesn't effect in my functionality.So can I consider that conversion as safe?

Comment: Please don't do that even if it's not potentially a problem, think a good solution rather than finding a workaround.

Comment: @krish `const char*` allows you to change what the pointer points to. `char* const` doesn't allow to change the pointer, but does allow to change the pointed-to data. I.e. `const` before `*` means the pointed-to data is `const`, but `const` after `*` means the pointer is `const`. You may find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916787/string-c-str-is-const) useful.

Comment: @iharibo may I know what will be the effect if i use that kind of cast there.