# Is it safe to dereference a temporary std::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management, stl

Is it safe to dereference a temporary std::shared_ptr?

Example:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::string> create_shared_string()
{
  return std::shared_ptr<std::string>(new std::string("hello"));
}

std::cout << *create_shared_str() << std::endl;
```

My fear is that the shared_ptr is destroyed and the reference counter goes to zero as soon as the dereference is complete and thus the returned raw pointer is no longer safe.

Comment: Add it as an answer maybe? ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[what is the lifetime of C++ temporary object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584824/guaranteed-lifetime-of-temporary-in-c)

in this case, the returned `std::shared_ptr` will not be destructed until `std::cout << std::endl;` is finished, so you can dereference it safely.