# C++ temporary object's lifetime

Tags: c++

```
void foo(const C &);
foo(C());
```

In this case, temporary `C` object lives until the end of `foo()`.

But my question is:

```
struct C { operator int(); }
void bar(int i);
bar(C());
```

In that case, Does temporary `C` object live until the end of `bar()`? If not, Is there any way to make temporary object live until the end of `bar()`?

edit: Thanks to user2109558, I know the code doesn't work. Then does the following code work well?

```
void bar(int i);
void bar(C &&c) { bar(c); }
```

Comment: The accepted answer is incorrect. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584824/guaranteed-lifetime-of-temporary-in-c

Comment: @MarkRansom Hmm..? So bar(C()) is OK?

Comment: Read the answers and judge for yourself. My conclusion is that it is OK.

Answer (score -2):

No！the code`bar(C());` 
is equal to 
 `int num = C();
  bar(num);`

So , temporary C object does not live until the end of bar() 
you have to change `bar` function parameter.such as `void bar(const C &)` or add global C object variable eg:

```
C c;
void bar(int i) {
 .....
```

}

but no suggestion do it.