# Is forced construction of unnamed variable like "Foo(12,3);" still a declarator?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider the following simple example:

```
struct A 
{
    int a;
    A(int b);
};

A *p;

A::A(int b) : a(b)
{
    p = this;
    std::cout << "A()" << std::endl; 
} 



int main()
{
    A(10); //What is it?
    std::cout << p -> a << std::endl; //10
}
```

I'm not sure that `N3797::8.5 [dcl.init]` may be applied here, because `N3797::8.5/1 [dcl.init]` says:

> A *declarator* can specify an initial value for the identifier being
>   declared. The identifier designates a variable being initialized

In the case there is no declartor. Which means that rule is not applicable.

If it's just a constructor call where does it specify int the Standard that expression of the form `class-name(argument_list)` allocate a fit amount of memory (What allocation function takes over that?) and initialize an object? I wish to acquire more details about how such expressions work?

Comment: `A a = A(10);` now do you see it?

Comment: Are you asking where in the standard it's defined that that's the syntax for a constructor call?

Comment: (The answer is [expr.type.conv])

Comment: I have changed the title to be a little more descriptive. I think as it is now it will be more 'findable' thanks to the 'unnamed' and 'declarator' terms. Please review and rollback or reedit if you don't agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A(10);
```

This is a discarded-value expression. According to [expr.type.conv],

> A *simple-type-specifier* (7.1.6.2) or *typename-specifier* (14.6)
>   followed by a parenthesized *expression-list* constructs a value of
>   the specified type given the expression list. If the expression list
>   is a single expression, the type conversion expression is equivalent
>   (in definedness, and if defined in meaning) to the corresponding cast
>   expression (5.4).

The 'corresponding cast expression' is `(A)10`, which in turn is equivalent to `static_cast<A>(10)` ([expr.cast]/4), and the `static_cast` is defined as [expr.static.cast]/4:

> Otherwise, an expression `e` can be explicitly converted to a type `T`
>   using a `static_cast` of the form `static_cast<T>(e)` if the declaration
>   `T t(e);` is well-formed, for some invented temporary variable `t`
>   (8.5). The effect of such an explicit conversion is the same as
>   performing the declaration and initialization and then using the
>   temporary variable as the result of the conversion.

And there you have your declarator.

Comment: Very useful remark about cast-exression. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't give a name, `A(10)` produces a temporary object of type `A`.

In the constructor of `A`, you assign the address of this temporary object to the pointer `p`. But the temporary object is destroyed at the end of the line `A(10);`. So you should not use the pointer `p` afterwards.

Comment: Interesting. Can you provide a reference describing that it's temporary?

Comment: The reference is 12.2 [class.temporary]. It is obvious that an object without name can only be temporary.

Comment: It's important to note that the program will likely crash (maybe not on your platform but on some other...)

Comment: Could you clarify why?

Comment: Because in the expression `p -> a`, the pointer p is bound to an object that has been destroyed. This results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: See this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584824/guaranteed-lifetime-of-temporary-in-c