# Is the lifetime of the temporary string long enough here?

Tags: c++, object-lifetime

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

std::string foo()
{
    return "Hello, World!";
}

int main()
{
    printf( "%s\n", foo().c_str() );
}
```

Comment: Yes. It is long enough.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584824/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is long enough. The string literal will cease to exist as the function returns, but at that point it has already been copied to a temporary `std::string`. That string will be copied (or will be created at the call site through copy elision) to the calling code. The resulting string will exist until the end of the expression, long enough to be passed to `printf`.

Comment: `The string literal will cease to exist as the function returns`, no it will not, string literals have static storage duration. It is irrelevant for the question tho.

Answer (score 0):

```
return "Hello, World!";
```

Returns a `std::string` (implicitely) constructed from the c-style string literal, and that can be considered as `static` in the function's scope.
The *temporary* `std::string`'s lifetime can be considered stable after returning from `foo()` in this case. It will be copied, or at least being *moved* with more modern standard implementations.