# Is a reference returned from a temporary variable valid?

Tags: c++, chaining, object-lifetime

I've come across a situation where being able to chain a method call to a temporary variable would be really helpful:

```
draw(Quad(0, 0, 1, 1).rotate(90));  // <-- .rotate() returns a Quad reference

struct Quad{
    Quad(float x, float y, float width, float height){...}
    Quad & rotate(float degrees){
        ...
        return *this;
    }
}
```

However, I'm unsure if the temporary variable will remain alive long enough for the `draw()` function to use it.  Is this safe to do?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584824/guaranteed-lifetime-of-temporary-in-c

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This particular use is safe. A temporary lasts until the end of the full-expression that creates it<sup>†</sup>; here, the full-expression is the whole statement, including the call to `draw`.

In general, this pattern could be dangerous. The following gives undefined behaviour:

```
Quad & rotated = Quad(0, 0, 1, 1).rotate(90);
draw(rotated);
```

In my opinion, I'd prefer the type to be immutable; rather than calling a function to modify an existing object, call a `const` function to return a new object, leaving the existing object intact.

<sup>†</sup>Unless its bound *directly* to a reference, which extends its lifetime to match the reference. This doesn't apply here, since it's not bound directly.

Comment: I like your answer better than mine, since you managed to actually give a concrete suggestion on how to write a better class, something I couldn't quite manage. Let's go with yours. :)

Comment: I agree. But isn't the same pattern the convention with assignment operators? If this pattern is dangerous, does that mean assignment operators are dangerous for the same reason?

Comment: @ChrisDrew: Yes, conventional class assignment operators also return references, so something weird like `T & t = (T() = x);` would give you a dangling reference. But sensible code is unlikely to assign to a temporary, or to bind the result of assignment to a reference, and there's no danger unless you do both these things.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the temporary `Quad` is destroyed at the end of the full expression (trailing `;`). So it's still alive when you call `rotate` on it, and still alive when you call `draw` with it as a parameter.