# const reference to temporary reference

Tags: c++, reference, language-lawyer, temporary-objects

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct CL
{
    CL()
    {
        cout<<"CL()"<<endl;
    }
    CL(const CL&)
    {
        cout<<"CL(const CL&)"<<endl;
    }
    ~CL()
    {
        cout<<"~CL()"<<endl;
    }
};

CL cl;

CL fnc()
{
    return cl;
}

int main() {
    cout<<"start"<<endl;
    const CL& ref=static_cast<const CL&>(fnc());
    //...Is "ref" valid here??
    cout<<"end"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What's lifetime of temporary object returned by fnc()? Is it lifetime of "ref" or of temporary reference static_cast(fnc()), which destroyed at end of statement?

Output of gcc (lifetime of fnc() is lifetime of "ref"):

```
CL()  //global object "cl"
start
CL(const CL&)
end
~CL()
~CL() //global object "cl"
```

Output of VS2013 (lifetime of fnc() is lifetime of temporary reference):

```
CL()  //global object "cl"
start
CL(const CL&)
~CL()
end
~CL() //global object "cl"
```

What's correct by Standard?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Guaranteed lifetime of temporary in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584824/guaranteed-lifetime-of-temporary-in-c)

Comment: Just wondering, what happens if you remove the `static_cast<>`? I'd expect both to behave the same then, just in case you have a real problem that you want to solve. Also, what's your interpretation of the standard concerning this issue?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt The `static_cast` is what makes all the difference here. Without it, the lifetime of `fnc()` is guaranteed to be extended to that of `ref`.

Comment: Thanks, @Angew. I'm aware that this is the way it must behave, but I was just trying to confirm that this undisputed rule is correctly implemented.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès that is not a duplicate, it does not cover the issues raised in this question.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I didn't mean to say that the answer to the OP's question is clear-cut. I just meant that *without the `static_cast`*, it is.

Comment: @Angew oh makes sense, I was wondering why you did not answer ;-)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt yes the `static_cast` makes a difference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe Visual Studio is correct here, this is covered in [defect report #1376](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1376) which says:

> In a declaration like
>
> ```
> T&& r = static_cast<T&&>(T());
> ```
>
> it is not clear what the lifetime of the T temporary should be.
>   According to 5.2.9 [expr.static.cast] paragraph 4, the static_cast is
>   equivalent to a declaration of an invented temporary variable t. The
>   lifetime of the temporary is extended to that of t, but it is not
>   clear what that lifetime should be, nor if the subsequent binding of t
>   to r would affect the lifetime of the original temporary. (See also
>   issue 1568.)

and the discussion includes this conclusion:

> The reference is bound to the xvalue result of the static_cast, so the lifetime of the temporary is not extended and this example results in a dangling reference.

and [defect report 1568](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_closed.html#1568) covers this case more specifically:

> According to 12.2 [class.temporary] paragraphs 4-5,
>
> > There are two contexts in which temporaries are destroyed at a different point than the end of the full-expression...
> >
> > The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary. The temporary to which the reference is bound or the temporary that is
> >     the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound
> >     persists for the lifetime of the reference...
>
> It is not clear whether this applies to an example like the following:
>
> ```
> struct S { };
> const S& r = (const S&)S();
> ```

and the response was:

> This issue is a duplicate of issue 1376.

so in this case:

```
const CL& ref=static_cast<const CL&>(fnc());
```

the reference is bound to the result of the `static_cast` and not to `CL` and therefore `CL` is a dangling reference.

For reference the relevant text from the draft C++11 standard section `5.2.9` *[expr.static.cast]*:

> Otherwise, an expression e can be explicitly converted to a type T using a static_cast of the form static_-
>   cast(e) if the declaration T t(e); is well-formed, for some invented temporary variable t (8.5). The
>   effect of such an explicit conversion is the same as performing the declaration and initialization and then
>   using the temporary variable as the result of the conversion. The expression e is used as a glvalue if and
>   only if the initialization uses it as a glvalue.

Comment: The resolution of DR1376 does not appear in C++17 so it seems there is more to this story ; it's not clear to me what the lifetime of the temporary materialized by the `static_cast` is.  If it is equivalent binding to the result of a declaration `T t(e)`, then `t` would last until the end of the current block  (current versions of g++ and clang both actually do it that way)