# Is 'this' a local variable?

Tags: c++, this, this-pointer

Here I am taking an example of overloading the increment operator:

```
 class Digit
 {
     int m_digit;

  public:
      Digit (int value)   //constructor
          {
            m_digit = value;
          }

      Digit& operator++();

      int ret_dig (){return m_digit;}
};

Digit& Digit::operator++()
{
   if (m_digit == 9)
        m_digit = 0;

   else  ++m_digit;
    return *this;
 }

int main ()
{
   Digit my_dig (5);
   ++my_dig;
 return 0;
 }
```

I have been told that local variables can't be returned. Isn't "this" a local variable? Here is what I think:

A pointer of type Digit is attached to the member function (overloaded operator function). When compiler sees the line ++my_dig, that is an instance of Digit class, it calls the member function. The address of the instance my_dig is passed as argument to the function and there is a hidden "const Digit*" named "this" to catch the argument. "this" is dereferenced(implicitly) to access m_digit, that is a member variable of class Digit. All the increment or wrapping is done inside the function and a reference to dereferenced "this" is then returned to the caller. Yes, this is the point to my confusion. If "this" is a local variable of type const Digit*, shouldn't it contain garbage when returned because "this" is going out of scope where the block ends haaa?

Comment: You can return a local variable. There is very little to stop you from doing it.The end result might not be what you expected or wanted, but you can do it.

Comment: The scope of a pointer variable does not affect the lifetime of the object it points to.

Answer (score 5):

`this` is an implicit parameter to all member functions which points to the object itself -- which has a strictly longer lifetime than the method.  The parameter itself is a local variable, but the object that it points to exists outside the method.

In this case the object is created on the first line of your `main` function and then lives until the `main` method exits.  Thus the object is safely alive throughout the call to `operator++`!

Comment: "this" is a parameter, right? All parameters are local to the function, but you are saying "this" is not local, can you please elaborate :-)

Comment: Yes, `this` is an implicit parameter to all member functions.  But it points to the object itself, which has a strictly longer lifetime than the function.

Comment: And dereferencing "this" will draw back the object. Thus, reference to the object is again sent back after incrementing the copy of member variable created for my_dig (in this case), right?

Comment: @user5241471 an interesting test of what is `this` is seeing what happens when you try to increment `this`. You'll find the behaviour is a little bit different then a normal passed-in parameter

Comment: I don't think that the object has a strictly longer lifetime than the method call. `delete this`, while unusual is a valid statement.

Comment: @MSalters: what you say is true, but I was trying not to overly complicate the answer with unusual edge cases.

Answer (score 2):

`this` is a local variable, but it is initialized by `&my_dig` when it enters the method.  The value of `&my_dig` has the same lifetime as `my_dig`, which ends at the end of the main block. So while `this` goes out of scope, the value of `this` is still valid.

Comment: Look the confusion here. This question has two answers. One saying "this" isn't local and other says "this" is local. Pretty confusing :-)

Comment: this is local, *this is not local. I think that is the distinction.

Comment: Sorry, I'm typing on a iPad that doesn't have back ticks

Comment: @MarkLakata, to access the back ticks on an iPad, you have to go the second page of symbols.

Comment: Both pages have only forward ticks for me. I just tried it.

Comment: `test two` woohoo. You need to hold the apostrophe key ... I didn't know that feature existed, I thought that was only Android

Answer (score 2):

The `*this` is the object and not a local variable. Any temporary objects which the compiler deems necessary to allocate, such as those needed to complete a expression, has a lifetime to the end of the expression.

This becomes interesting for objects which has a destrctor, as the destructor run not when the individual parts of the expression is completed, but when the entire expression completes -- hence your `*this` variable will survive just sufficiently long to complete what is needed.

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584824/guaranteed-lifetime-of-temporary-in-c) for deeper discussion

Comment: Thanks, that helped :-)