# What is the difference between those two ways to call a function objects?

Tags: c++, functor

I have simple question, and yet i could not find any answer.

Let's say i have a function object:

```
template <typename T>
class MyFunctionObject {
private:
    //...
public:
    double operator()(T value) {
        //...
        return double_value;
    }
}
```

What is the difference between those two "lines":

```
double value = MyFunctionObject <int> ()(1000);
```

and

```
MyFunctionObject <int> functor;
double value = functor(1000);
```

Comment: Very little, except that in the first the functor isn't named.

Comment: @Carcigenicate in the 1st case; when functor will go out of scope? Right after execution, or at the end of the local scope (function in with it is called)?

Comment: If that's your question, it looks like this may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584824/guaranteed-lifetime-of-temporary-in-c My C++ is rusty though, so I can't answer that. I also didn't vote to close as a duplicate since I'm not sure. Read the link over though.

Comment: The lifetime of the first function object expires after the expression is evaluated.

Comment: @Carcigenicate OP's question in the comments is the same as your link, although the question as it is posted is not

Comment: @PasserBy That's true. Nix the duplicate part of the comment. Still worth a read-over though.