# Is there any difference between these two ways?

Tags: c++, string, char

I wrote a function called ws2s to convert wstring to string:

```
std::string ws2s(const std::wstring & src)
{ 
   std::string res = "";

   size_t const mbs_len = wcstombs(NULL, src.c_str(), 0);

   std::vector<char> buffer(mbs_len + 1);

   wcstombs(&buffer[0], src.c_str(), buffer.size());

   res.assign(buffer.begin(), buffer.end() - 1);

   return res;
}
```

I use valgrind to run for memory check got some error. There is any difference between these two ways to call function ws2s?

First method:

```
std::string xml_path = ws2s(something);
const char * path = xml_path.c_str();
```

Second method:

```
const char * path = ws2s(something).c_str();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first method you call the function and assign the result to a local variable. Then you get the pointer to the data held by the `string` object. This is all fine and the proper way to do this.

In the second method you call the function and assign to a variable a pointer to the data held by the temporary result object. The temporary object is then destroyed [at the end of the full expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584824/guaranteed-lifetime-of-temporary-in-c), freeing the data pointed to by your variable. This creates a dangling pointer, whose dereference causes undefined behavior.

You may use such syntax if you need to use the pointer only before the end of the expression (without copying it), e.g.:

```
std::strcmp(ws2s(something).c_str(), "test");
```

Answer (score 2):

In the second example, the temporary object (return value of `ws2s`) is destroyed after the call to `.c_str()`, thus your pointer in `path` becomes invalid.

In the first example, of course, this is not the case, and the pointer will be valid as long as you keep `xml_path`.