# What is the lifetime of the arrow indirection operator (operator->) return value?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, object-lifetime

While a normal overload of the arrow operator typically returns a plain pointer, as [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) notes, it doesn't have to:

> The overload of operator -> must either return a raw pointer, or return an object (by reference or by value) for which operator -> is in turn overloaded.

When the operator returns an object by value, what is the lifetime of that object?

Naively, I could imagine two different ways of it working. Either the returned object is lifetime preserved until the statement is complete, or the returned temporary is "discarded" immediately after the subsequent `operator->` is called on it.

For example:

```
class A {
    class A_sub {
         A_sub(...);
         int foo();
    }

    std::unique_ptr< A_sub > operator->() {
        return std::make_unique< A_sub >(...);
    }
}

int main() {
    A a;
    int val = A->foo();
    return val;
}
```

When is the destructor for A_sub permitted to be called? Is it prior to the call to foo(), or is the returned unique_ptr lifetime preserved until foo() completes? (Does it depend on deep the drill down behavior goes?)

It seems to me that the "obvious" answer would be that all `operator->` return values would be preserved until the ultimate completion of the statement (due to lifetime issues as demonstrated above), but I'm unsure if the C++ standard guarantees such ordering.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584824/guaranteed-lifetime-of-temporary-in-c