# C++ One-liner. Is it legal to construct an object and call a function on the same line

Tags: c++

This code appears to break on one widely used compiler with optimizations enabled, although it works fine in Visual Studio.

```
struct foo
{
    foo(int a) { s[0] = '0'+a%10;s[1] = '\0'; }
    const char * bar() const { return &s[0]; }
    char s[4];
};

int main( )
{
    const char * s = foo(1234).bar();
    printf("%p %s\n", s, s);
}
```

I expect that even though foo is an rvalue, that it will be constructed on the stack, and 's' will point to valid data.
However, with GCC (versions 7.5 and 9), the buffer is never initialized.

Example failing compile line:

```
g++-9 --std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -O3 -o example example.cpp
```

Comment: make the s variable volatile.

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/q/584824/2864740 - I think since C++11 things may have been codified better (mainly at the end of the expression, not scope or compiler specific). Note that *s is dangling after the expression.

Comment: It would be expected to work without the local *s variable.. `printf("%s\n", foo(1234).bar());` as the expression is not ended yet.

Comment: The lesson here is that "it works fine" can be one possible (unreliable) manifestation of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On this line:

```
const char * s = foo(1234).bar();
```

`s` is pointing to the `char s[4]` member of a temporary `foo` object. At the end of the full expression, this object dies, and `s` is now pointing to invalid memory. Printing it on the next line will invoke undefined behavior.

---

The issue here is with the use of the return value of `bar()`. The chained function call itself is fine, so if you use the expression directly in the `printf` it's well-defined:

```
printf("%s\n", foo(1234).bar());  // ok
```

Comment: how about auto&& s=foo(1234).bar();? would that still be undefined behavior?

Comment: @HikmatFarhat yes that is still UB, references only extends lifetime of objects they refer to, not function return pointer of a temporary internal buffer. Ie `auto && f = foo(); const char *s = f.bar();`  is better